# How can I automate my code instead of manually change values?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, automation, data-manipulation

I have a code for a alluvial ggplot. I will like to make my code to a function, so it will be automatic instead of write the same code for different values. The only thing you have to change is the data, how can I do so?

This is my current code

> ```
>  ggplot(as.data.frame(allu),
>    aes(y = allu$Freq, axis1 = allu$a1, axis2 = allu$a2, axis3 = allu$a3,axis4 = allu$a4, axis5 = allu$a5, axis6 = allu$a6, axis7 = allu$a7, axis8 = allu$a8)) +
>    geom_alluvium(aes(fill = allu$a1), width = 1/12) +
>   geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
>   geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE) +
>   scale_x_discrete(limits = c ("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8"), expand = c(0.02, 0.02)) +  >     scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
>   ggtitle("CLL")
> ```

Can i make this code to a function that will automatically run the plot without manually type in the values but only change data?

Comment: Turn it into a function where ```x``` is the dataframe. Something like ```myFunc <- function(x){ ggplot(as.data.frame(x), aes(y=x$Freq ...``` As long as your dataframes are consistent

Comment: Do you want to feed in dataframes of the same shema or do you want to run the code for different variables of one dataframe?

Comment: The last one! Run the code for different variables of one dataframe

Comment: Avoid using "$" inside aes.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? What's `allu` like? Which packages did you import other than `ggplot2`? What's the expected output?

Comment: For looping over different variables you can use the aes_string argument instead of aes. It allowes you to pass the targetvariable as string, stored in a temp-variable: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177129/ggplot-and-loops

Comment: How can i make an If else statement that says if limits are above a8 it will go false? can i do that

Comment: How can i make an If else statement that says if limits are above a8 it will go false? can i do that

Answer (score 0):

probably like this
(note: I just copied your code, have not tested if it actually works)

```
myfunction <- function( data_ ) {
  ggplot( data_,
     aes(y = data_$Freq, axis1 = data_$a1, axis2 = data_$a2, axis3 = data_$a3,axis4 = data_$a4, axis5 = data_$a5, axis6 = data_$a6, axis7 = data_$a7, axis8 = data_$a8)) +
    geom_alluvium(aes(fill = data_$a1), width = 1/12) +
    geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
    geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c ("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8"), expand = c(0.02, 0.02)) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
    ggtitle("CLL")  
}
```

and then call using

```
myfunction( data_ = as.data.frame(allu) )
```

Comment: Avoid using "$" inside aes.

Comment: How can i make an If else statement that says if limits are above a8 it will go false? can i do that